# Snowflake SQL, converting number YYYYWW into date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, implicit-conversion

in snowflake i have numeric column with values like 202201, 202305,202248 that refers to year week combination. How can i convert it into first or last day of tha week?
for example 202251 will be '2022-12-19' or '2022-12-25' (as the week starts on Monday)

thx for help

i have tried

```
select distinct week_id
,to_date(concat
  (
   substr(week_id,1,4)
  ,substr(week_id,5,2)
  )
  ,'YYYYWW'
) as Date_value
from MyTable
```

but i got only error msg as Can't Parse '202249' as date with format 'YYYYWW'

Answer (score 1):

If we swap to TRY_TO_DATE form, it will not explode, which can make for simpler debugging.

And then when we try 'YYYYWW' we see if fails:

```
select week_id    
    ,try_to_date(week_id, 'YYYYWW') as Date_value
from values
    ('202201'),
    ('202305'),
    ('202248'),
    ('202249')
    t(week_id);
```

| WEEK_ID | DATE_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 202201 | null |
| 202305 | null |
| 202248 | null |
| 202249 | null |

swapping to a substring for just the year, and a number for the week:

```
select week_id    
    ,try_to_date(left(week_id,4), 'YYYY') as just_year
    ,try_to_number(substr(week_id,5,2)) as week_num
from values
    ('202201'),
    ('202305'),
    ('202248'),
    ('202249')
    t(week_id);
```

now we get those parts as something workable.

| WEEK_ID | JUST_YEAR | WEEK_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202201 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 202305 | 2023-01-01 | 5 |
| 202248 | 2022-01-01 | 48 |
| 202249 | 2022-01-01 | 49 |

Now we can use [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html) and the [WEEK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#supported-date-and-time-parts) like so:

```
select week_id    
    ,try_to_date(left(week_id,4), 'YYYY') as just_year
    ,try_to_number(substr(week_id,5,2)) as week_num
    ,dateadd(week, week_num, just_year) as answer
from values
    ('202201'),
    ('202305'),
    ('202248'),
    ('202249')
    t(week_id);
```

| WEEK_ID | JUST_YEAR | WEEK_NUM | ANSWER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202201 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2022-01-08 |
| 202305 | 2023-01-01 | 5 | 2023-02-05 |
| 202248 | 2022-01-01 | 48 | 2022-12-03 |
| 202249 | 2022-01-01 | 49 | 2022-12-10 |

which can all be merge into one like:

```
select week_id    
    ,dateadd(week, try_to_number(substr(week_id,5,2)), try_to_date(left(week_id,4), 'YYYY')) as answer
from values
    ('202201'),
    ('202305'),
    ('202248'),
    ('202249')
    t(week_id);
```